# Transition from an image to a video on fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have a fancybox gallery with images and video. When I click on an image and use the mouse scrollwheel I can browse through the various images, but it always skips the video. If I click on the video, it plays well and everything...

I would like to be able to go to my video when browsing through the gallery images...

this is the website I'm doing it on [www.charbelnicolas.com](http://charbelnicolas.com) (Please click on the II for the second page to see the gallery that I'm talking about)

Now... the image and the video have the same `rel` which is `"gallery2"` and this is the code I'm using for the galleries:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox({ helpers: { title: false } });});

    </script>


    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fancybox-media').fancybox({ 'minWidth': 720, 'minHeight': 480, helpers : { media : {}}});});

    </script>
```

What should I do so I can see the navigation arrows on my video and that when I use the keyboard or mouse scrollwheel while browsing through the gallery I can see the video along with the images? (so it no longer skips the video)

I've searched the google groups discussions and I have seen various answers from JFK but I can't seem to make it work... maybe if you guys check my website you might be able to tell me what's wrong.

Thank you

Comment: BTW, the video is the one with the green image that says "Te de limon"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need a single script for both, images and videos.

If you want to pass options like the `minWidth` and `minHeight` for your video, do it using (HTML5) `data-*` attributes (e.g. `data-min-width="720"` and `data-min-height="480"`) within your link like :

```
<a rel="gallery2" class="fancybox" href="http://vimeo.com/59469665" data-min-width="720" data-min-height="480"><img class="left" src="http://charbelnicolas.com/thumbs/anunciotedelimonthumb.png" alt="" /></a>
```

Then fetch those values within the `beforeShow` callback like :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    beforeShow: function () {
        this.minWidth  = $(this.element).data("min-width");
        this.minHeight = $(this.element).data("min-height");
    },
    helpers: {
        media: {}
    }
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ftg8/)**

P.S. Don't forget to load the `jquery.fancybox-media.js` file.